# How do I use auto slice correctly

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "slicer-gui.py", line 17, in

File "os.py", line 225, in makedirs

PermissionError: 【WinError 5】 拒绝访问。: 'log'

I hope to use it, thank you